# How to href within JQuery field for RemoteObjects

Tags: jquery, remote-objects, hyperlink

Morning Everyone,

I was wanting some help in hyperlinking the Name field in the following code.  I've tried a few methods within the brackets to no avail and keep breaking the entire page.  I'm using RemoteObjects and I'm not sure if I needed to paste the rest of the page on here but I'm using Daniel's code from here --> http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/11/23/datatables-in-visualforce-part-2/

```
{ 
    "data": "_props.Name",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},
{ 
    "data": "_props.Invoice_Amount__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},
{ 
    "data": "_props.Invoice_Date__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},                          
{ 
    "data": "_props.Invoice_Details__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},                                               
{ 
    "data": "_props.Invoice_Type__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},                        
{ 
    "data": "_props.Client_Firm__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},                         
{ 
    "data": "_props.Client_Firm_ID__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
},                         
{ 
    "data": "_props.On_Hold__c",
    "defaultContent": '' 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502387/datatables-hyperlink-on-all-rows-in-a-column) post to add hyperlink.

You can use `render` function with `columnDefs` to override the display type:

Here is what I use in dataTable's option:

```
"columnDefs": [{
    "targets": 1,
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        return '<a href="'+full._props.Id+'">' + full._props.Name + '</a>';
    }
}]
```

Comment: Hey @RahulSharma - I'm trying to give you credit for you the answer.  I appreciate the time you took to help me!

Comment: Also, if you are in the States, Happy Thanksgiving!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RahulSharma,

This is what I had to do to make it work.  Thanks a ton, what you did helped me figure it out!

```
               "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 1,
                    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ){
                     return '<a href="/'+full._props.Subscription__c+'">' + full._props.Subscription_Name__c + '</a>';
                    }
                    }],               

                // Specify our columns. The first column is used to control expanding and collapsing to see changes.
                "columns": [
                    { "class": 'details-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": '',
                        width: "8%" },
                    { "data": "_props.Name",
                        "defaultContent": '' },
                    { "data": "_props.Invoice_Amount__c"
```

Comment: Instead of posting solution as a comment, would be better to update your post with it!

Comment: I wanted to leave the issue at the top and solution at the bottom to show people that are using Daniel's example and then scroll down to the solution.  This way others with my issue can compare/contrast between his code and what they need for a solution.  If you still think it needs to be changed, let me know.  - Louis M.